# Making an extension to notify when text field filled by website

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, background

I'm trying to make an extension work. It's supposed to play a sound and display a notification when a value has been inserted in a text field by the website which auto-refreshes every minute.

For the notification, I have found this code that does work fine, which I put in background.js:

```
createNotification();
audioNotification();

function audioNotification(){
var yourSound = new Audio('notification.mp3');
yourSound.play();
 }

function createNotification(){
var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",
          message: "Your message",iconUrl: "your_icon.png"}

chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

//include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},5000);}
```

So if a value has been allocated to the text field, I need the notification code to be executed.

I have tried putting an if and then statement before the code above, but it seems that it doesn't work. I do not have a content.js file, or should I?

Comment: Google Chrome does not let you play audio through the browser without the user interacting with a button on the webpage first if I recall correctly, this permission would be reset on every page load.

Comment: Let's suggest it's not for the sound notification, what command should I use in content.js in order to load and execute the code above?

Comment: I don't know what `content.js` is.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I don't have a content.js because I don't know how to use it. All I know is that I need to trigger background.js and that it can only happen from content.js?

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? `content.js` can be anything

Answer (score 0):

I've changed course, and used a script in Tampermonkey instead.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('app_date');
var word = '2019-';
var textValue=textarea.value;
if (textValue.indexOf(word)!=-1)
{
var yourSound = new Audio('https://www.memoclic.com/medias/sons-wav/0/230.mp3');
yourSound.play();
}
```